# C# listbox select and unselect item in MultiExtended mode

Tags: c#, listbox

When I click on a unselected item in a listbox it will be selected. The client wants that if you click again (so without using the cntrl key) it deselects.

But I tried many things but nothing works. So is this possible and if possible can some one explain me how by using some C# code?

Comment: Is this a windows application or an ASP.Net app?

Comment: have you consider to use MultiSimple mode ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350514/winforms-listbox-append-selection/11350601#11350601

Comment: I didn't use MultiSimple because I thought this didn't had the behavoure I wanted (yes that simple) But this is just what I want thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This will unselects All/Specific ListBox items when you click on Blank Space of ListBox.

```
        private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int totalHeight = listBox1.ItemHeight * listBox1.Items.Count;

            if(e.Y < totalHeight && e.Y >= 0)
            {
                // Item is Selected which user clicked.

                if(listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && listBox1.SelectedItem != null) // Check if Selected Item is NOT NULL.
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index : " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index : No Items Found");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // All items are Unselected.
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                MessageBox.Show("Selected Index : " + listBox1.SelectedItem); // Do NOT use 'listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim()' here.
            }
        }
```

> And also you can change the code with what you want to do when item is selected/unselected.

- Leave Comments if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to do this with the built-in options. My solution is to programatically send a virtual Ctrl keypress when the mouse is over the Control (so the user doesn't need to press or think about anything). If you don't need the additional functionality of `MultiExtended` try using `MultiSimple` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

If you do, here's the ugly solution:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const byte KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;
    public const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;

    private void listBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, (byte)0, 0, 0);
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, (byte)0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
```

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11351431/62671).

Comment: @NominSim You don't need to hit the Ctrl key. A virtual keypress is performed programatically.

Comment: Ohh I see now, you're right about it being ugly, but +1 anyways.

Comment: This answer deserves two upvotes. Well, you have answered twice so you get the two upvotes!!

Answer (score 1):

You could add something in the selected index event that if the selected index is the same as the preciously selected (keep it stored somewhere), then set the selected index to -1, so nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Adhere to the `SelectedValueChanged` event and add this:

```
string selected = null;

private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    if (lb == null) { return; }
    if (lb.SelectedItem != null && lb.SelectedItem.ToString() == selected)
    {
        selected = lb.SelectedItem.ToString();
        lb.SetSelected(lb.SelectedIndex, false);
    }
    else 
    {
        selected = lb.SelectedItem == null ? null : lb.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```